# Moment Generating Function for a discrete random distribution

Tags: statistics

(Discrete uniform distribution) A discrete random variable is said to be uniformly distributed

if it assumes a nite number of values with each value occurring with the same probability.

If we consider the generation of a single random digits, then $Y$ , the number generated, is
uniformly distributed with each possible digit,$ 0, 1, 2, ... , 9$ occurring with probability $\frac{1}{10}.$
In general, the density for a uniformly distributed random variable X is given by

$f(x) = 1=n , \text{ where : n is a postive integer and }  x = x_1, x_2, ... , x_n$

Find the moment generating function for the discrete uniform random variable X.

- I don't know how to approach this with what I have from class... all I can come up with is

$m(t) = \text{ (sum) } e^{tx} \frac{(1)}{(n)}$ which I know is complete rubbish. I am grasping so little of this so any assistance in what a moment generating function is and the concepts needed for this question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, what you wrote is fairly close to what needs to be done. Your random variable $X$ takes on the values $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$, each with probability $\dfrac{1}{n}$.

The moment generating function $M_X(t)$ of $X$ is, by definition, $E(e^{tX})$. By the usual formula for expectation,
$$M_X(t)= E(e^{tX})=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}e^{tx_k}.$$
That's all there is to it!

For this "general" case, there is really nothing further to do, since no genuine simplification is possible.

In the special case where the $x_i$ are separated by constant amounts, we can do some simplification. Let's look at your random digits example.
In that case,
$$M_X(t)=\frac{1}{10}\left(e^{0}+e^t+e^{2t}+\cdots +e^{9t}\right).$$
We have here a geometric series with common ratio $e^t$. By the usual formula for the sum of a finite geometric series, we get
$$M_X(t)=\frac{e^{10t} -1}{10(e^t-1)}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, just a question on the last step: should it be 1-e^10 and 1-e^t? Or are those the right way around?

Comment: It doesn't matter. We can get to your version by multiplying top and bottom by $-1$. And it is $e^{10t}$, not $e^{10}$.

Comment: Man, sometimes I just don't see math, thank you :)